# Python bindings for Microsoft UI Automation?

Tags: python, windows, winapi, automation, pywin32

Anybody know of any Python bindings for Microsoft UI Automation?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327.aspx

without having to use IronPython. I am aware of the excellent pywin32 work, but Microsoft UI Automation is supposed to be the successor of the Active Accessibility layer, which I have been using on Windows XP. I need to migrate of the "Active Accessibility" functionality (event triggers on open windows, focus controls, etc.) to a Windows 7 platform.

Thanks!

Comment: Active Accessibility will still work on Windows7. There's no need to migrate from using MSAA to UIA unless you want to use new functionality in UIA that's not in MSAA.

Comment: thanks. That's a relief. Until there are Python bindings for UIA, I think I'm going to stick with pyAA, although it is dead as a project.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on [Cobra](https://github.com/ldtp/cobra)

> Cobra WinLDTP is based on Linux Desktop Testing Project -
>   http://ldtp.freedesktop.org LDTP works on
>   Windows/Linux/Mac/Solaris/FreeBSD/NetBSD/Palm Source, yes its Cross
>   Platform GUI testing tool.

They claimed it based on Microsoft DLL's (.NET3.5) - (Interop.UIAutomationClient.dll, UIAComWrapper.dll, WUIATestLibrary.dll)

I manage to use it with python for testing HTMLlayout app.

Answer (score -2):

This maybe what you would like to use.It allows you to call UIAutomation using python and what you need to do is just update the demo file.https://github.com/chengzi/PyUIAutomation

Comment: The link is dead and I could not find another reference.

Comment: [How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer): *"Provide context for links: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline."*