# python:how to copy/replace text on internet textbox using hotkey

Tags: python, winapi

This has been bugging me for the last few days.

What I'm trying to achieve is:
1. Select(by dragging, shift, etc) text from an internet text editor.
2. press a hotkey (Alt-` in the code below)
3. Retrieve/copy that text to python program
4. Replace the selected text with a different block of text.

So if I select the word "stack" in a text editor and press Alt+`, then the selection should change into "stack overflow".
With the press of that hotkey only.

It seems pretty easy, but I found out that it really isn't.

This is as far as I've gotten:

```
import pyHook
import win32clipboard
import win32api, win32con

def sm():
    handle = win32api.GetCurrentProcess()
    win32api.SendMessage(handle ,win32con.WM_COPY, 0,0)

def OnKeyboardEvent(event):
    if event.Alt != 0:
        if event.KeyID != 192:
            sm()
            try:
                win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
                a = win32clipboard.GetClipboardData(13)
            finally:
                try:
                    win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()
                finally:
                    print "error"

    return True

hm = pyHook.HookManager()
hm.KeyDown = OnKeyboardEvent

hm.HookKeyboard()
if __name__ == '__main__':
  import pythoncom
  pythoncom.PumpMessages()
```

This is just one of the many codes I've tried.
I'm not even sure if WM_COPY is the right message to use. In fact, I don't really get what messages are supposed to do and how they work.
Retrieving the text is just the first part of the whole program and I'm stuck.

I don't care if I use the clipboard to make this happen.

Any ideas? I really want to make this work, because I do this tedious replacement every day.

Comment: what does this `win32clipboard.GetClipboardData(13)` do exactly? it seems having to do with the ENTER key, how do you actually read the copied data from clipboard?

Comment: The 'GetClipboardData(13)' returns data in the clipboard in unicode format. So if the string 'Hello' has been copied, variable 'a' will now have 'Hello' assigned to it. That's just me trying to figure out if the stuff I want actually ended up in clipboard.

Comment: You are looking for [UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009.aspx) (see also [Python bindings for Microsoft UI Automation?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5487263/1889329)). The clipboard belongs to the **user**. Don't abuse it for your own purposes. It's a shared resource, and you are destroying the **user's** data.

Comment: maybe it would be better to implement this functionality in the internet editor itself (if it is sth you have access, like your app editor or sth)